# Django Smart Selects not working for django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-smart-selects

So I'm trying to implement django-smart-selects 1.5.9 for django 1.11.4 and somehow the chained keys dont work the way they should.
`models.py`

```
class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("province")
        verbose_name_plural = _("provinces")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class District(models.Model):
    province = models.ForeignKey(
        Province, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("district")
        verbose_name_plural = _("districts")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    district  = models.ForeignKey(
        District, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("city")
        verbose_name_plural = _("cities")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Ward(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=2
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("ward")
        verbose_name_plural = _("wards")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class School(models.Model):
   # other fields .....
    province = models.ForeignKey(
        Province, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        blank=True,
        null = True,
        verbose_name = _("province")
    )
    district = ChainedForeignKey(
        District,
        chained_field="province",
        chained_model_field="province",
        show_all=False,
    )
    city = ChainedForeignKey(
        City,
        chained_field="district",
        chained_model_field="district",
        show_all=False,
    )
    ward = ChainedForeignKey(
        Ward,
        chained_field="city",
        chained_model_field="city",
        show_all=False,
    )
```

`urls.py`

```
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
```

`admin.py`

```
@admin.register(School)
class SchoolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ServerInline, ServerUpdateInline]
    list_display = ['school_name', 'school_type','phone', 
    'province', 'district', 'city', 'ward',
]
    search_fields = ('school_name','district__name')
    list_filter = ('school_type', 'district')
```

here tried the chained dropdown implementation from [django-smart-selects](https://pypi.org/project/django-smart-selects/)
the models and admin are on a seprate app called school and the url i provided is on the base django directory's url.py

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current url is

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^admin/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
```

I checked the [docs](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) and they use `chaining` instead of `admin/`. Could you try following their docs and see if that works?

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
```

Comment: tried that as well, it doesn't work

Comment: Were there any errors in Django or in the browser console? Could you post them here if there are any?

Comment: no, there's no error in console or terminal. It only lists the provinces but the other dropdowns are empty and i've added a screenshot of the dropdown's apperances.

Comment: did you set `JQUERY_URL = True` in your settings.py?

Also, could you try to remove or comment out `city` and `ward` just so the `School` model only contains `district` chained foreign key and see if that works.

I saw a github issue that might be related to your case: https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects/issues/316

And it seems that the package doesn't support multiple chained foreign keys in one model

Comment: I had  `USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = True` in settings.py and changing it to `JQUERY_URL=True` raises the error `AttributeError at /en/admin/school/schoolprofile/add/
'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/school/schoolprofile/add/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'
Exception Location: C:\chained_admin\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py in absolute_path, line 90`

Comment: Alright. I don't have much idea on what's going on there but yeah, your settings.py looks correct.

Have you tried my other suggestion?

> Also, could you try to remove or comment out city and ward just so the School model only contains district chained foreign key and see if that works. I saw a github issue that might be related to your case: github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects/issues/316 And it seems that the package doesn't support multiple chained foreign keys in one model

Comment: Yeah, its that the package doesnt support multiple chainedforeignkey in one model. Do you have any idea how i can implement the functionality in django admin. I did it in client side with some modelform modification and using ajax to load required districts related to province and so on

Comment: i think it would be the same concept within django admin where you have to  perform some modifications, check the exposed endpoints of the districts and related province, add listeners to the dropdowns